# Select maximum based on assumed value

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle DB 18c

I need to select the most "severe" record per student, based on a string value in column "OUTCOME". The challenge for me is that I cannot simply select MAX(OUTCOME), since as a string, this becomes an alphabetizing issue, rather than a "severity" selection.

There are four possible values. In order of severity, they are: 'Close to Average', 'Slightly Raised', 'High', 'Very High'.

From the sample table below...

-- student 2's most severe outcome is 'Very High'.

-- student 3's most severe outcome is 'Slightly Raised'.

-- student 4's most severe outcome is 'High' (even though alphabetically, 'Slightly Raised' would be the max)

```
STUID  OUTCOME
    2  Very High
    2  High
    3  Close to Average
    3  Slightly Raised
    4  High
    4  Slightly Raised
```

I found a way to return the value I need, but it seems perhaps overly complicated. Wondering if there are any more efficient ways to handle this?

Basically, I select max based on a decode numeric value taken from the strings. Once I have the numeric value, I decode it back to it's string value.

```
SELECT DECODE(MAX(DECODE(UPPER(OUTCOME), 
                  'CLOSE TO AVERAGE', 1, 
                  'SLIGHTLY RAISED', 2, 
                  'HIGH', 3, 
                  'VERY HIGH', 4)), 
       1, 'CLOSE TO AVERAGE', 
       2, 'SLIGHTLY RAISED', 
       3, 'HIGH', 
       4, 'VERY HIGH') 

FROM ...
```

Any ideas on how to do this more elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

That's more database design question (3rd normal form). Normally you should have special table to store your constants and their additional properties like priority/severity, etc.

So it would be better to create additional table, something like

```sql
create table OUTCOMES(
   ID   int GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY primary key,
   NAME varchar2(30) unique,
   SEVERITY int
);
begin
   insert into OUTCOMES(NAME,SEVERITY) values('CLOSE TO AVERAGE', 1);
   insert into OUTCOMES(NAME,SEVERITY) values('SLIGHTLY RAISED', 2);
   insert into OUTCOMES(NAME,SEVERITY) values('HIGH', 3);
   insert into OUTCOMES(NAME,SEVERITY) values('VERY HIGH', 4);
   commit;
end;
/
```

After that you can join this table and sort by severity.

Answer (score 0):

Would you prefer something like below ?

`data` is the table here

```
select studid,outcome
from
(
select t.*,row_number() over (partition by studid
order by decode(outcome,'Close To Average', 1, 
                'Slightly Raised', 2, 
                'High', 3, 
                'Very High', 4) desc) rn
from data t
)
where rn = 1
```